# Subview doesn't remove after calling from ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, subview

I have added a `UIBlurEffect` with a function to load it before the data load from the server. I added a `boolean` parameter to active or deactivate it.

```
func addingEffectLayerWithSpinner(active: Bool){
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    if active {
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    } else {
        //This one is not working
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

and here in `viewDidLoad`, I pass `false` to the that function to remove the `UIBlueEffect` view, but it doesn't work, could you help me what is the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    addingEffectLayerWithSpinner(active: true)

    profile.showingProfile { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            // Sucesss response from server
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nameLabel?.text = nameOfUser!
                self.avatar?.downloaded(from: avatarUrl!)

                //This one is not working
                self.addingEffectLayerWithSpinner(active: false)
            }
            // failed response from server
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
```

The problem is here. As every time the above blurEffectView is called, a new UIVisualEffectView is prepared which is different from what's presenting now.

```
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
if active {
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
} else {
    //This one is not working
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

So you may consider to save the blurEffectView as a property and then call to remove it.

```
var  blurEffectView :  UIVisualEffectView!

func addingEffectLayerWithSpinner(active: Bool){

//introduce a false condition early: 
if !active {  blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
 return
} 

let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.light)

blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
//remove `let` here
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

}